# How to change ncol in a list of ggplots using grid.arrange() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing some coding using R.
I have got a list of ggplots called "plots" with 10 plots:

```
is(plots)
[1] "list"           "vector"         "AssayData"      "vectorORfactor"
is(plots[[1]])
[1] "gg"
```

By calling:

```
do.call(grid.arrange,plots)
```

it generates a graphic with 3 columns.

How can I change the number of the columns?

I tried:

```
do.call(grid.arrange(ncol=2),plots)
```

But I get:

```
Error in do.call(grid.arrange(ncol = 2), plots) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'what' in selecting a method for function 'do.call': Error in unit(rep_len(1, nrow), "null") : 
  'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

Any clues on how to fix this?

Comment: `do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots, ncol=2))`

Comment: Yes thanks. I have also just figured it out myself!